# KeyError: 'mnli' error when using roberta model from meta hub

Tags: python, pytorch, fairseq

I tried to use the `roberta` model from the torch hub, as:

```
import torch 
roberta = torch.hub.load('pytorch/fairseq', 'roberta.large')
tokens = roberta.encode('Roberta is a heavily optimized version of BERT.', 'Roberta is not very optimized.')
roberta.predict('mnli', tokens).argmax()  # 0: contradiction
```

but I am getting the following torch error:

```
│   458 │
│   459 │   @_copy_to_script_wrapper            
│   460 │   def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> Module:
│ ❱ 461 │   │   return self._modules[key]
│   462 │
│   463 │   def __setitem__(self, key: str, module: Module) -> None:
│   464 │   │   self.add_module(key, module)
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────
KeyError: 'mnli'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried changing `'mnli'` in your code to something else that exists?

Comment: The issue is that `self._modules` is empty. So, the `roberta.large` is not getting in any where.